# Firestore: How can I update a data model after releasing a project?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am creating a project using Firebase and I will release the project soon. Let's say I have a `users` collection in database and what should I do to add a property to every `user` documents after releasing the project? How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to write code to query the collection, iterate every document, and update the new field in that document.  There is no shortcut to this; there are no migrations that you can perform like some SQL databases.  You might choose to write a utility for this so you can reuse code, but the code will still have to run to read and write each document.